# history -c does not reset $HISTCMD to 1

Tags: bash

TL;DR: If your history begins to truncate (e.g., your `HISTSIZE` is 400 but you've typed so many commands that your history number is 500), resetting your history with `history -c` will clear `HISTSIZE` or fewer lines from your history, and subtract that many from your history number, but will not reset it to 0 (in the example, it would reset it to 100). How can I completely reset the history number back to 0?

I know this belongs on Unix and Linux. I posted it there on [August 16](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463017/history-c-does-not-reset-histcmd-to-1) and no one has been able to answer, so I'm posting it here in the hope that that other guy, Charles, or chepner can help.

---

Bash 4.2 (and also on 4.4). I want my history numbers to be under 4 digits. relevant bashrc sections:

```
HISTSIZE=99
HISTFILESIZE=100
#ignores back-to-back duplicate commands, not those that start with a space
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
#ignore commands fewer than 5 characters long because we can type those
HISTIGNORE="?:??:???:????:?????:history"
```

the history number as seen with `history` or `\!` in the PS1 will obviously go beyond these values. I want to be able to reset the history number down to ~100 when it goes above 1,000.

`history -c` clears the terminal history, but that only reduces the history number by the amount of commands that it cleared, e.g.:

```
j:~$ history | wc -l
99
j:~$ echo $HISTFILESIZE
100
j:~$ echo $HISTCMD 
1203
j:~$ history -c
j:~$ echo $HISTCMD
1106
```

So... how do I drop the history number down to a smaller number, such as `$HIST(FILE)SIZE`. This is in a tmux session, but I don't think that should matter.

None of the solutions provided work. Here's what they do with `set -x`:

[image: history -c doesn't clear history]

Comment: Consider [unix.se] for questions about interactive shell use, as opposed to script development.

Comment: I know =(. I posted there almost 2 months ago and didn't get any answers though. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463017/history-c-does-not-reset-histcmd-to-1